# Review system keep question in review but not close votes

Tags: bug, review-queues, vote-to-close

A question can only be in the [close vote review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) is someone already vote for. I just came on [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/34152907) for [How to Rewrite Custom Post URL With Taxonomy or Category Slug Appended Before the Post Slug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75860458/10952503) and It says I'm the first vote but it's wrong (never see this post before). Before voting, it were saying it had 3 others votes. But, with 3 votes, it should be closed.

I see others posts with 3 votes recorded for the same reason which should not appear. This issue appear sometimes with like 2 votes for something, I check and the question and only one is showed.

Does review system remove some votes?

Comment: [The timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75860458/timeline) suggests it was sent to the close vote queue from a flag. So, the lack of votes is understandable there. However, if it showed votes initially, then it would be a problem. It either counts flags or shows stats for a random question instead of the one being reviewed. The close votes couldn't have expired, that takes a lot longer.

Answer (score 8):

[VLAZ's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424009/review-system-keep-question-in-review-but-not-close-votes#comment952753_424009) is correct: the close review task was showing the "Needs improvement" flags that were raised to recommend closure.

Here's the moderator view of the timeline (with the names other than yours removed), showing the three "recommend closure" flags:

[image: mod view of the timeline as described above]

Incidentally, that review task now only shows your single close vote, presumably due to the flags having been marked helpful by your close vote, which seems like it's arguably a bug:

[image: This question has been flagged as: Needs details or clarity: This question should include more details and clarify the problem. (1)]