# Show leave open/close votes in review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

This question is related to my [previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424009/10952503), with the objective of seeing all votes.

When doing [close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) and [reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats) reviews, we see previous votes (or flags sometimes...). We can see how many people vote for which one. It's very useful, mostly for directly checking if we approve of this vote. For example if it's a typo, duplicate or off-topic, we will handle them differently.

But, in the case of no agreement with the first vote, we don't know if other people chose to keep the question as-is. The problem is we don't know if we are alone to think it should be reopen. Do we miss the issue? Do we just don't have the knownledge for this? (mostly true for typo questions) Or do people agree with us and the close vote is wrong? We would not know. So, I simply skip this question.

Is it possible to add this option?

Comment: Why does it matter to you what someone else thinks about the question? If you cannot decide by yourself, you should Skip. If you can decide by yourself, you should not care about other votes.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi because I don't want to take bad decisions, and as we are not seeing everything, I want to be sure to don't pass by of something

Comment: When I have any concerns about a review, I go to the source question. It's saved me from a few tricky audits in the past.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure this is worth the tradeoff for the benefit gained.

As MisterMiyagi [put it quite well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424056/show-leave-open-close-votes-in-review-queue#comment953102_424056):

> If you cannot decide by yourself, you should Skip. If you can decide by yourself, you should not care about other votes.

In principle, you shouldn't be taking other people's agreement, or lack thereof, into account (they might be wrong!).

You [note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424056/show-leave-open-close-votes-in-review-queue#comment953103_424056) that you want this feature

> because I don't want to take bad decisions, and as we are not seeing everything, I want to be sure to don't pass by of something

While I could believe that an especially careful reviewer could make good use of being able to see other reviewers' votes before casting theirs in order to double-check for mistakes (especially if the votes weren't shown at first and were behind a click or something to that effect), I believe that it would be far more likely to bias the average reviewer into being more likely to simply agree with the existing votes.

You also bring up the case of typos: generally, there's a comment or answer explaining the typo.  If that's not the case, then...well, the close voter probably should have left one if they wanted the question closed.  Expecting reviewers to fully go through the effort of independently figuring out what the answer to a question is to determine if it's a typo isn't really reasonable (and it's also sort of unsporting not to tell the asker if you do know the answer, especially because they should confirm if that really is the issue and edit the question to address that if it's not).

Comment: Today we could also simply agree with existing vote by selecting same close vote reason as the most vote now, and we have a real biai which is that people hate all post and no one should be keep opened/closed

Comment: I mean...you're not wrong.  I guess the theory here is that we're already, by definition, showing at least one vote in favor of closure, might as well shown any votes against it, too, to balance it out?  This would be an interesting A/B test, although I'm not sure we have enough reviewers for statistical significance.